# st_intersects with ST_Dump throws PostGIS exception

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-join, spatial-query

I have a query in my lines and points table.

My lines table includes MULTILINESTRING, MULTILINESTRING Z, LINESTRING geometry type data.

```sql
select *
from sde.line h2
left join sde.points b
on st_intersects(st_startpoint(ST_LineMerge((ST_Dump(h2.shape)).geom)), b.shape);
```

I am using `st_dump` and `st_linemerge` because `st_startpoint(line2.geometry)` is coming null. So, I am converting to linestring.

But this throws exception `"[42804] ERROR: argument of JOIN/ON must not return a set"`

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems here.
You need to move the set returning function to a subquery instead of in the join condition.
You should also move the dump after the linemerge.  Linemerge returns linestring only if the geometry can be merged to linestring or else it returns multilinestring.
In case you have multilinestrings after the linemerge, you should instead just select the first point of the first geometry - I assumed your lines table has an id column.  Add any other columns you require into the subquery select.

```
select 
    *
from
    (select id, st_pointn(st_geometryn(shape,1),1) as shape from sde.line) h2
left join
    sde.points b
on
    st_intersects(h2.shape, b.shape);
```